# How to train Models with numpy arrays bigger than 6GB?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I have couple of huge training files I am planning to train. The validation data is also perfect and I see no problem but the SIZE is huge. I am talking about 20GB+. Loading one file crashes python due to Memory error

I have tried making the file to one but it's too big
[image]

```
X = np.load('X150.npy')
Y = np.load('Y150.npy')
```

Error

```
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\lib\format.py in read_array(fp, allow_pickle, pickle_kwargs)
    710         if isfileobj(fp):
    711             # We can use the fast fromfile() function.
--> 712             array = numpy.fromfile(fp, dtype=dtype, count=count)
    713         else:
    714             # This is not a real file. We have to read it the

MemoryError:
```

I need a solution so I can train huge datasets.

Comment: Once in a need to do any serious computations and train ( .fit() ) ML-predictors and do any further analyses with N [GB] files, the best next step is to acquire an appropriate computing platform. Having less RAM than your data-file sizes is possible ( numpy.memmap-files are a cheap option to work via a small cached data-window into a disk-only data-object ) **but one will pay an immense costs** of having **~ 10000-100000x slower random-access times** than having all data kept inside an in-RAM-layout. Have used .memmap()-s for ML for a few years, before having affordable RAM-enough sized fabric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Important: First make sure that your python is 64bit. The methods below only support files upto 2GB for 32bit python versions

Typically, one should use `np.memmap()` to use the array without loading on to the RAM. From the [numpy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html), "Memory-mapped files are used for accessing small segments of large files on disk, without reading the entire file into memory."

Example usage:

```py
x_file = "X_150.npy"

X = np.memmap(x_file, dtype='int', mode='w+', shape=(300000, 1000))
```

However, since your files as already stored as .npy files, I stumbled upon `np.lib.format.open_memmap()` which creates or loads memory mapped .npy files.

The usage would be as follows, identical to what you'd do with np.memmap():

```py
x_file = "X_150.npy"

X = np.lib.format.open_memmap(x_file, dtype='int', mode='w+', shape=(300000, 1000))
```

Here's the docs for the second function (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4620395/6941749)):

```py
>>> print numpy.lib.format.open_memmap.__doc__

"""
Open a .npy file as a memory-mapped array.

This may be used to read an existing file or create a new one.

Parameters
----------
filename : str
    The name of the file on disk. This may not be a filelike object.
mode : str, optional
    The mode to open the file with. In addition to the standard file modes,
    'c' is also accepted to mean "copy on write". See `numpy.memmap` for
    the available mode strings.
dtype : dtype, optional
    The data type of the array if we are creating a new file in "write"
    mode.
shape : tuple of int, optional
    The shape of the array if we are creating a new file in "write"
    mode.
fortran_order : bool, optional
    Whether the array should be Fortran-contiguous (True) or
    C-contiguous (False) if we are creating a new file in "write" mode.
version : tuple of int (major, minor)
    If the mode is a "write" mode, then this is the version of the file
    format used to create the file.

Returns
-------
marray : numpy.memmap
    The memory-mapped array.

Raises
------
ValueError
    If the data or the mode is invalid.
IOError
    If the file is not found or cannot be opened correctly.

See Also
--------
numpy.memmap
"""
```